# How to stop Connection Line from snapping to object in Keynote

Tags: keynote, iwork

In Keynote I am inserting multiple connection lines to a single image. As soon as I drag one end point near the image the end point of the connection line snapped onto the image.  I would like to have complete manual control over the positioning and depth of connecting lines. How do I stop Keynote from auto snapping my connection line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments, to control the endpoints in the connecting line hold down the <kbd>⌘</kbd> while dragging the endpoint to the desired position on the object. Be sure to click on the desired location before you release the <kbd>⌘</kbd>!

Comment: This seems to disconnect the line from the shape permanently. Is there a way to maintain the connection to the shape, while changing the connection point?